# Bamboo OnDemand run as administrator

Tags: bamboo

my team is using Bamboo OnDemand and have a custom made Image built on the default image for Bamboo OnDemand.

We have some things in our build process which needs to be running in administrator mode.
How should I configure the machine?`

I can't find any windows service called Bamboo to run as administrator.

I have found the Bamboo user it runs under but it wont work if I add the user to the Administrators group

Answer (score 0):

I did a bad thing and just disabled UAC.